# Python Pandas CSV Loop

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two csv files:  androiddata.csv and iphonedata.csv

I have to do the following:

**a) Compute the average download speed(download_kbps) for android devices in United States(server_country).**

**b) Compute the average download speed(download_kbps) for iphones in Taiwan(server_country).**

I'm extremely lost, as I don't know how to conditionally extract either US or Taiwan.

Ideally I thought:

```
iPhoneData= pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Hanna/Desktop/Sheridan College/Statistics for Data Science/Assignment1/iphone_data_sample.csv")
```

then:

```
count = 0
for row in iPhoneData:
     if (row.server_country == "US"):
         count += row.download_kbps
```

then I would divide by how many Us selections there were to get the average.

But that code doesn't work/exist

I just don't know how to do this with pandas. I'm so hilariously lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Pandas loc to fetch the row which satisfies a condition :

```
dUS= iPhoneData.loc[iPhoneData["server_country"]=="US","download_kbps"]
avg_US = dUS.mean()
```

Similar procedure can be done for Taiwan also.